# iOS - Remove color on navigation and tabbar items

Tags: ios

I want to remove the color that lays over the tab bar and navigation bar items so the icons I use will have the colors they have. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Are you talking about the tint color? It's recommended to create your images in white, that way you can make the resulting color be anything you want in code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will work but you can try `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`. Example for tab bar:

```
UIImage *your_image; // do not forget to initialiuze it!
your_view_controller.tabBarItem.image = [your_image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```